# Long iptables rules efficiency & performance

Tags: iptables

When building a long iptables rules, which one is more efficient, to use one long script per line or to use the tables? What about the performance, does it have effect to packets loss and untracked packets?

Example:

1. one script per line

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. using the tables

   ```
   iptables -N table1
   iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j tbl1
   iptables -A table1 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```

Comment: To performance test see http://people.netfilter.org/kadlec/nftest.pdf and https://strongarm.io/blog/linux-firewall-performance-testing/

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you define a new chain called table1, and route incoming packets to the new chain in order to perform matching on the chain.

This can be a good strategy if, for example, the processing you do on that chain is somewhat heavy and you don't want to subject all incoming packets to it.

But in your example,

- ALL incoming traffic on the wlan0 interface is sent to the new chain (this even includes packets that are part of established connections!)
- The processing on that chain is trivial - just matching by source and destination port.

So in this simple example the extra complexity of defining a new chain and routing everything to it is unnecessary and redundant, and were you able to measure a performance difference, would probably result in the lower performance.

Performance really won't affect you unless you have a lot more rules or much heavier processing.

Comment: It is true, from my experience (just tested it) more chains will make it more heavier. I'm using a metered data connection, It consumes more bandwith when I use more chains, and using more REJECT. It also consumes more bandwith if I use DROP insted of REJECT. But I think more chains is more secure than simply write many rules at one with less chains. I'm just wondered how windows do it, it consumes less bandwith downloading using IDM software (tested it years ago) from the internet than any linux.

Comment: If efficiency is a priority at all, you should accept any related or established packets as early as possible. You may already be doing this in rules that weren't part of your example, but I mention it just in case.